# Fullcalendar is showing event in next month, How can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

this is my starting date in full calendar

```
start: new Date('2016', '02', '07', 00, 30)
```

But while loading calendar this event is showing on 2016 march 07
how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Use "03" instead of "02" for the month?

Comment: I hope it should 01 right @webo80

Comment: i did the same . thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will have always add up one month, while using Calender

Here in your case : start: new Date('2016', '01', '07', 00, 30)

Consider you months starts from 0

```
var month = new Array();

month[0] = "January";

month[1] = "February";

....

month[11] = "December";
```

You can refer this simple eg : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp